# How to create Binance test API key

Tags: api, binance

I'm trying to build a Binance trading bot, I generated an API key and can use it with a real money, but I need to test the bot using their test -sandbox- account
I looked in the documentation and couldn't find out how to create a testing API key

Where can I found it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this : https://testnet.binance.vision/
Sign in with github and then press Generate HMAC_SHA256 Key

Answer (score 21):

For futures testnet, register and login here: https://testnet.binancefuture.com/

You will see "**API KEYS**" tab in the panel just below the main chart panel

(the other tabs in this panel are: Positions(0) / Open Orders(0) / Order History / Trade History / Transaction History / Assets / and, finally, API Key)

I hope this will save your time

Comment: Wow, that is what I call "hidden info"... thank you

Comment: Mine panel is empty: No API Key or API Secret.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by adding base_url="https://testnet.binancefuture.com", so my client creation looks like this - `cm_future_client = CMFutures(key=binance_future_api_key, secret=binance_future_api_secret, base_url="https://testnet.binancefuture.com")`